# Grouping Play 2.0 views into packages/folders

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to solve possibly simple problem, in my 'views' directory, in typical Play framework setup, I would like to group my templates (*.scala.html files) into groups, possibly using another folder for each group, eg. I would like to have customers folder with the following files in it:

- `createForm.scala.html`
- `editForm.scala.html`
- `list.scala.html`

So far so good but when I try to access that view reference from my controller (eg. `Ok(views.html.list(..))` -> `Ok(views.customers.html.list(...)`), I get an error:

```
object customers is not a member of package views
```

Is there any best practice/receipe on how to work with multiple views, how to gather them into groups and then how to use them in other views or controllers.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way the template engine works is that a template defined as:

```
/views/application/index.scala.html
```

Will be turned into a class:

```
views.html.application.index
```

So basically `views.html` is always kept as a prefix. Cf. the [Play template documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaTemplates).

In your case that means it should be

```
Ok(views.html.customers.list(...))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a closer look at the `target` directory, you'll see how views are compiled and the packages are made:

```
Ok(views.html.group.view())
```

You can also import like this:

```
@import views.html.group._
//...
Ok(view())
```

Comment: thx, accepted gourlaysama as he was first, anyway thx for the import hint